# wildcard Search with cts.fieldValueMatch for dateTime datatype

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I have used FieldValueMatch to do wildCard search for `dateTime` datatype, but its throwing an error when I use the pattern same as string

```
cts.fieldValueMatch("submittedOn", "2020*", ["case-insensitive"], cts.collectionQuery("customers"))
```

Am I using the pattern in the wrong way? Can someone please suggest

Comment: What options were used to create the Field, and what error are you getting when you attempt to use `cts.fieldValueMatch`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the error that you are getting?

> [javascript] XDMP-ARG: cts.fieldValueMatch("submittedOn", "2020*", "case-insensitive", cts.collectionQuery("customers")) -- arg2 is invalid

You are querying with a `string` pattern.

> $pattern   A pattern to match. The parameter type must match the lexicon type. String parameters may include wildcard characters.

In order to be able to perform a wildcarded `string` value match, you need to have a `string` range field index on that `submittedOn` field. You can have multiple indexes on the same field.

Comment: Thanks for responding and yes that was the error and it did work if I change the datatype to string but the problem is submittedOn is persisted in the db in this format "2020-05-19T23:55:11.076+0000" and we show it in a different format on the UI (28-Apr-2020 21:54:30 GMT-7 ) so if I change the rangeIndex type to string I would be forced to search it in the format as its in the DB. is there a way that I could do wildcard search using this pattern 28-Apr-202 for the same field?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand. You can index it as both a `dateTime` and as a `string`, and the raw input from users could be parsed as a `dateTime`, for instance using `xdmp.parseDateTime()`: `xdmp.parseDateTime("[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]", "28-Apr-2020")` and then format or utilize various dateTime components to construct a variety of different query constructs.

Comment: Got it. But how do we convert wildcard search pattern to datetime using xdmp.parseDateTime()? For instance if the user enters 28-Ap and I want all those documents with date 28 and month april ( and is stored as  "2020-05-19T23:55:11.076+0000" in DB)